# Is there a phrase in English for working days like "one day in work, and one next day off"?

Tags: phrase-request, phrases

Do there have many phrases to describe for the working days of the week? 
Like usually I have seen:

- "5 working-day", as known as Monday to Friday.
- "6 working-day", as known as Monday to Saturday.

I'd like to know if there have other phrases like these below:

1. Someone who work full-time in 1 day and take-off 1 next day, and repeat whatever the day-in-week.
2. Someone who just out for work at night, cleaner services, like restaurants, clubs & bars, etc.

Comment: He works [24-hour shifts on] *alternate days*.

Comment: For 2, they work a night shift.

Answer (score 2):

As an American, I would say "I work every other day" for the first and would be prepared to explain more.

For the second, I would say "I work nights."

Comment: A lot of Brits might say "I work one day on, one day off".

Comment: "would be prepared to explain more."  This can be emphasised.  This would be a very unusual work pattern in the UK (or USA). You would certainly need to explain this.

Comment: I have colleagues who work three days out of five, which are Monday, Wednesday, and Friday.